# change FILTER CRITERIA for display (in views)

Tags: views

[image]I want to have different filter criteria for one display in my views. I added it and when i hit "Update preview", the data shows up as expected in the bottom area of my views window. But then, when I surf to the url or when I hit the link specified at **Path**, I get data that appears without that filter applied. I have hit the save button on top, too. What else am I missing?

**edit 1**
Also, I have realized that my second display also shows the title of my first display but I can reach it on the alternate path url...

**edit 2**
*see screenshot in better resolution at: http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=5c2a5fe*
screenshot: On the left screen, you can see the view settings and on the right screen, in the April 2014 & May 2014 sections, you can clearly see that the filter *Content: Title (contains Brunch)* doesn't get recognized

Comment: Just to verify: your're using the regular filter (not exposed) in the page display (not block, attachment..), am I right? Is the AJAX option turned on or off?

Comment: Might you try using Contextual filters.

Comment: Do you have caching enabled in view settings or any other caching like APC, Memcache, Varnish etc?

Comment: @Rotem Yes, regular, exposed checkbox is not checked. Use AJAX: is set to No.

Comment: @JSinha Caching under ADVANCED is set to None

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. I don't have any caching set in the view itself and I don't have any other special cache modules installed and cleared Drupal's internal cache (under performance)...

Comment: Are you using 'relationship'. If not, make relationship for that related field table. Or try use other filter , is it working basic things.

Comment: @JSinha How would I use RELATHIONSHIPS best? I don't see my fields with the content showing up at all...

Comment: Guess, may be this permissions problem.  Check "views access" permission for anonymous users. Or may be somewhere it is hidden. If still problem exists, can u attach view screen shot.

Comment: @JSinha It should not be a permission issue as I am using this as admin (and user), also the permission is set to "view published content" which is fine for all other content - please see the **edit 2** and screen shot above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Filter criteria didn't get applied properly because both Displays had the same name. It is required that both View displays have different names to be able to apply filters to only one Display.